# Google maps api containsLocation always returning false

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have drawn a polygon with google maps and tried to include a location that is in the polygon but the containsLocation function always returns false. Not sure if the points on the polygon have to start and end at the exact same location, or if there's an issue with my code.

The location for my containsLocation lat lng is in the shape.
[image: Here is the polygon i drew]

```
var rightShoulderFront = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: outerCoords
});
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapSect"), {
  center: { lat:3.528319665937775,lng:101.7580347776062 },
  zoom: 5,
});


var outerCoords =[
  {lat:3.528319665937775,lng:101.7580347776062},
  {lat:3.003044444012029,lng:101.4085838669952},
  {lat:2.9951223092598767,lng:101.82611927913445},
  {lat:3.5216453,lng:101.7636108}
]

      geocoder.geocode({address: selectedFullAddress,},function(results,status)
      {
        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
     
        var curPosition     = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(curPosition, rightShoulderFront)
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following will help. I rearranged things a little and made a some minor mods but essentially the same. In the original you were calling `outerCoords` as  avalue before it had been declared so I'd imagine there were errors in the console.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: </title>
        <style>
            #mapSect{
                width:100%;
                height:100vh;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function initMap(){
                // It is unclear where "selectedFullAddress" is defined hence manually assigning here.
                const selectedFullAddress='Jalan Chengal, Kampung Melayu Subang, 40150 Shah Alam, Selangor, Malaysia';
                
                const map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("mapSect"), {
                    center: { lat:3.528319665937775, lng:101.7580347776062 },
                    zoom: 5
                });
                
                const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                
                // very basic function to add simple marker to aid visualisation
                const addmarker=function( pos,i ){
                    let marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                        position:pos,
                        title:i + ' [ '+pos+' ]',
                        map:map,
                        draggable:true
                    });
                    return marker;
                };
                let bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                var outerCoords =[
                    {lat:3.326413,lng:101.258009},
                    {lat:3.388127,lng:101.787869},
                    {lat:2.9951223092598767,lng:101.82611927913445},
                    {lat:3.003044444012029,lng:101.4085838669952},
                    
                ];
                var rightShoulderFront = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    paths: outerCoords,
                    strokeColor: '#0000CC',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                    strokeWeight:1,
                    fillColor:'red',
                    fillOpacity:0.25
                });
                
                // iterate over coordinates and extend the bounds object
                outerCoords.forEach( (obj,i)=>{
                    bounds.extend(obj);
                });
                
                map.fitBounds( bounds );
                rightShoulderFront.setMap( map );
                
                
                geocoder.geocode({ address: selectedFullAddress },function(results,status){
                    lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    var curPosition     = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                    var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(curPosition, rightShoulderFront)
                    if( isWithinPolygon ) addmarker( curPosition, 'Found Address: '+isWithinPolygon )
                    console.info(results,isWithinPolygon,status)
                });
                
                
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>&callback=initMap'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='mapSect'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have issues with the posted code:

1. A javascript error: `InvalidValueError: not an Array` on this line: `var rightShoulderFront = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: outerCoords});` because `outerCoords` is not yet defined, and `null`/`undefined` is not an Array.
2. A javascript error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: geocoder is not defined` on this line: `geocoder.geocode({address: selectedFullAddress,},function(results,status)`, because `geocoder` is not defined in your code.
3. A javascript error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: selectedFullAddress is not defined`, because `selectedFullAddress` is not defined in your code.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/e6f2mopu/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var outerCoords = [{
      lat: 3.528319665937775,
      lng: 101.7580347776062
    },
    {
      lat: 3.003044444012029,
      lng: 101.4085838669952
    },
    {
      lat: 2.9951223092598767,
      lng: 101.82611927913445
    },
    {
      lat: 3.5216453,
      lng: 101.7636108
    }
  ]
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapSect"));
  var rightShoulderFront = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: outerCoords,
    map: map
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < outerCoords.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(outerCoords[i]);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);


  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var selectedFullAddress = "Kuala Lumpur"
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: selectedFullAddress,
  }, function(results, status) {
    lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: results[0].geometry.location,
      map: map
    })
    var curPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(curPosition, rightShoulderFront);
    if (isWithinPolygon) {
      infowindow.setContent("isWithinPolygon:" + curPosition.toUrlValue(6));
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#mapSect {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mapSect"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the reason why my code wasn't working was because the bounds wasn't drawn, hence it always returned true